# Windows start application on remote host

Tags: windows, powershell, deployment, amazon-ec2

currently I am writing a deployscript for our build system.
I have an ec2 machine that i want to push my installer to, install the program and then run the program (exe). The program is in fact a server that should run forever. I already tried doing this with Powershell Remoting, this is not satisfying because a permanent connection is needed (if the powershell remote session disconnects, the process terminates).

Now I am looking into Invoke-WMIObject, is this really the best way to go, or am I missing something obvious? 
Requirement is that the whole build process can be run from a powershell script (which is executed by our build server).

The server is running windows 2008 Server R2

kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run your server program as a Windows Service - just wrap it with one of available free service wrapper utilities like [nssm](https://nssm.cc). You can use PSRemoting to recreate and start the service on the remote server each build by running `Stop-Service`, `& nssm remove`, `& nssm install` and `Start-Service`.

Alternatively (though probably not so easily managed in your build), you could remotely create and run a task in Task Scheduler with [Scheduled Tasks Cmdlets](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649816%28v=wps.630%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PsExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) from SysInternals, but that's a standalone utility. However, you can still embed the logic in your PS script. If you are still in need of WMI, then you might wanna check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742610.aspx). It includes snippets of VB scripts and a detailed explanation of what to do.